# Java RegEx: Replace part of source string

Tags: java, regex

If the source string contains the pattern, then replace it with something or remove it. One way to do it is to do something like this

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(sourceString);
while(m.find()){
  String subStr = m.group().replaceAll('something',""); // remove the pattern sequence
  String strPart1 = sourceString.subString(0,m.start());
  String strPart2 = sourceString.subString(m.start()+1);
  String resultingStr = strPart1+subStr+strPart2;
  p.matcher(...);
}
```

But I want something like this

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(sourceString);
    while(m.find()){
      m.group.replaceAll(...);// change the group and it is source string is automatically updated    
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: `'something'` that wouldn't compile, it's not a character but a string.

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace a pattern in your string with something else? Did you try `String#replaceAll("pattern","replacement")`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> `// change the group and it is source string is automatically updated`

There is no way what so ever to change any string in Java, so what you're asking for is impossible.

To *remove* or *replace* a pattern with a string can be achieved with a call like

```
someString = someString.replaceAll(toReplace, replacement);
```

To *transform* the matched substring, as seems to be indicated by your line

```
m.group().replaceAll("something","");
```

the best solution is probably to use

- A `StringBuffer` for the result
- `Matcher.appendReplacement` and `Matcher.appendTail`.

Example:

```
String regex = "ipsum";
String sourceString = "lorem ipsum dolor sit";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(sourceString);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

while (m.find()) {
    // For example: transform match to upper case
    String replacement = m.group().toUpperCase();
    m.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
}

m.appendTail(sb);

sourceString = sb.toString();

System.out.println(sourceString); // "lorem IPSUM dolor sit"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to replace all occurences of a certain pattern, try this:

```
String source = "aabbaabbaabbaa";
String result = source.replaceAll("aa", "xx");  //results in xxbbxxbbxxbbxx
```

Removing the pattern would then be:

```
String result = source.replaceAll("aa", ""); //results in bbbbbb
```

Comment: This is a good approach unless you need to *transform* the matched substring.

Comment: @aioobe Exactly, I was struggling to explain that. That exactly what I want to do. To transform the matched substring and somehow put it back in the original string.